# How to detect a click in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I do follow this
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/displaying-the-coordinates-of-the-points-clicked-on-the-image-using-python-opencv/

```
# importing the module
import cv2
  
# function to display the coordinates of
# of the points clicked on the image
def click_event(event, x, y, flags, params):
 
    # checking for left mouse clicks
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
 
        # displaying the coordinates
        # on the Shell
        print(x, ' ', y)
        p1 = (x,y)
        print('p1 =', p1)
        # displaying the coordinates
        # on the image window
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        cv2.putText(img, str(x) + ',' +
                    str(y), (x,y), font,
                    1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('image', img)
 
# driver function
if __name__=="__main__":
 
    # reading the image
    img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg', 1)
 
    # displaying the image
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
 
    # setting mouse handler for the image
    # and calling the click_event() function
    cv2.setMouseCallback('image', click_event)
 
    # wait for a key to be pressed to exit
    cv2.waitKey(0)
 
    # close the window
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

now on  `p1 = (x,y)` if I want detect other click on other(p2) how can I do.
thank for read and hope you can help me :)

Comment: Does this help? p1 = (x)
print(f'p1 = {p1}')

p2 = (y)
2print(f'p2 = {p2}')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from my understanding you want to increase the number every time you click. If so this is how you would do that, apologies if I misunderstood.

```
i = 1
def click_event(event, x, y, flags, params):

# checking for left mouse clicks
if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    global i
    # displaying the coordinates
    # on the Shell
    print(x, ' ', y)
    p1 = (x,y)
    txt = ('p{num: d} =')
    print(txt.format(num=i), p1)
    i +=1
    # displaying the coordinates
    # on the image window
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(img, str(x) + ',' +
                str(y), (x,y), font,
                1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, I want to get value of x,y on image by click on that image and get variable to p1(frist click) and second click get value to variable p2 and third click get value to variable p3. I will only click three times and different click of x,y.